# Selecting a single entry from a many-to-many relation in yii

Tags: yii

I have the following database structure. Actually, it's a bit more complex, but I'm showing only the relevant portion. The structure is predefined and can not be changed, as it needs to be synchronized with another DB.

[image: my DB schema (simplified)]

The classifier can be something like color or size. So basically this structure allows to say that `Product A` is `big` and `red`, while `Product B` is `small` and `green`.

I am getting this data from another DB and it guarantees that there is only one entry per classifier per product (i.e. the product can not be `red` and `green` at the same time). Also, the classifier IDs are predefined (say, `1` for `color` and `2` for `size`).

How do I make a relation in my `Product` model in such a way as to get the classifier entry as an attribute, i.e. `$product->Color` and `$product->Size`?

In other words how do I do this:

```
 SELECT * FROM product AS p
 LEFT JOIN xref_table AS x ON (p.ProductId = x.ProductId)
 LEFT JOIN classifierEntry AS classifierColor ON
   (x.ClassifierEntryId = classifierColor.ClassifierEntryId
    AND classifierColor.ClassifierId = 1)
 LEFT JOIN classifierEntry AS classifierSize ON
   (x.ClassifierEntryId = classifierSize.ClassifierEntryId
    AND classifierSize.ClassifierId = 2)
```

...in an elegant and efficient manner?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [afterFind](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#afterFind-detail) to run a custom algorithm, that will populate for me the `Color` and `Size` properties.

Doing this with relations, is overkilling, keep in mind Keep it simple rule.

You can cache the lookups into Memcache, if you access them frequently.

Comment: Does this imply lazy-loading?

Comment: That's probably not a good idea if I need to display the list of all items that are `red`.

Answer (score 0):

The question is how much you need to do it completly based on relations.
One option would be do to it as **get** functions, which behage like properties:

```
public function getColor() 
{
  $product =  .. // get the color data via SQL statement, using e.g.  Yii::app()->db->createCommand
  return $product->ClassifierName
}

public function getSize() 
{
  $product =  .. // get the size data via SQL statement, using e.g.  Yii::app()->db->createCommand
  return $product->ClassifierName
}
```

Because actually relations do the same - they just select the data and present it to you as a "property".
You can redefine any property by a function called simply **getProperty** and that will act like `$model->property`